# Auto resize drop down navigation menu

Tags: css, menu, tabs, autoresize

I'm having a problem with adapting my CSS for devices with smaller screens.
When I resize the browser to have smaller viewport, a part of the navigation menu gets hovered by others, making impossible to click on button from above.

```
ul li{
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    font-size: auto;
    width: 10em;
    height: 2em;
    margin-right: 0.25em;
    line-height: 2em;
    background-color: #666666;
    opacity: .7;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid white;
}
```

Comment: Please show us your html as well! (see [mcve])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve using VH on size, sorry for all!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="table" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="link" />
<h3 draggable="false" class="unse">
<ul>        
<li><a onClick="location.href='link'">Home</a>
<ul>
<li><a onClick="link'">Homepage</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<div/>
```

it is a example of HTML.